autocomplete no muestra datos al publicar en servidor externo
Mi problema es el siguiente, hice un input que se autocompleta, utilizando ajax, php y mysql. En mi servidor local (XAMPP) funciona perfectamente, pero al momento de subirlo a un servidor privado para publicar mi sitio, dejo de funcionar el autocomplete.
Al inspeccionar en RED muestra ok el metodo GET y en respuesta muestra los datos correctos pero ademas muestra un codigo el cual no se muestra en servidor local.
Podria ser x permisos o alguna incompatibilidad ?  Ayuda....


Si tu respondes con json válido y la respuesta trae más cosas, claramente tu alojamiento está intentando ser listo y añade cosas que no debería, especialmente si la respuesta debería ser JSON y no HTML. De todas maneras es absolutamente imposible ayudarte a partir de una imagen de la respuesta... no somos adivinos. Necesitamos ver el código de la llamada, la respuesta y saber qué alojamiento estás usando, porque parece que esté inyectando algo que no debería. Como he dicho, sin saber exactamente cómo se está haciendo... es imposible decir nada más
